# Like reloading data without refreshing, but in python

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, page-refresh

I have some jQuery code similar to this:

```
var refreshStuff = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        // get some data from database and show it on html page
    });
}, 5000);
```

Basically, code is used to constantly refresh one part of html page which is the most recent data from database...

Is it possible to do such thing in python (version 2.x) and how? Thanks for any tips/urls ;-)

Comment: What do you mean? jQuery is running on the client side, which Python doesn't (normally). If you're running Python on the server, it just has to handle the HTTP requests coming in from AJAX pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write web application, there are a lot of tools for Python. It can be small web frameworks like Bottle, or big frameworks like Django. It also could be just Python, but frameworks will make your development easier.

Comment: Ah yes, simple google query like "django ajax" has done the trick :) Thanks :)